# multiple route file instead of one main route file in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I am a novice in web developing with Laravel 5. I installed asGgardCMS and After seeing asgardCms codes, I found that there is nothing codes in app/Http/route.php file and required codes for routing be placed in Modules codes. For example required code for routing menu manager module be placed in Modules/Media/apiRoutes.php and Modules/Media/backendRoutes.php  files. May help me and tell me how I can manage my routes like that?

Comment: @loghman Please post a concrete scenario of something you want to do and the problems you've encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load custom route files within a Service Provider. AsgardCMS is doing it the same way, see this method in the Core RoutingServiceProvider that loads the backend routes:

https://github.com/AsgardCms/Core/blob/master/Providers/RoutingServiceProvider.php#L77

The Laravel docs provide a simple example in the package development section:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/packages#routing

Answer (score 16):

The group() method on Laravel's Route, can accept filename, so we can something like this:

```
// web.php

Route::prefix('admin')
    ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));

// admin.php
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
```

Answer (score 13):

1. create 2 route files `routes.web.php` and `routes.api.php`.
2. edit the `RouteServiceProvider.php` file to look like the example below:

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * This namespace is applied to the controller routes in your routes file.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $webNamespace = 'App\Http\Controllers\Web';

    protected $apiNamespace = 'App\Http\Controllers\Api';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        //

        parent::boot($router);
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router)
    {

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Web Router 
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->webNamespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.web.php');
        });

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Api Router 
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->apiNamespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.api.php');
        });

    }
}
```

Note: you can add as many route files as you want...

Answer (score 10):

You can create as many route files as you need anywhere and then just require them in the main route file smth like:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});

Route::post('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});

require_once "../../myModule1/routes.php";
require_once "../../myModule2/routes.php"
require_once "some_other_folder/routes.php"
```

where you will define routes in the same way as in main

Comment: simple, fast and easy ✔

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Request::is()` so your main `routes.php` file will look like this:

```
if(Request::is('frontend/*))
{
    require __DIR__.'/frontend_routes.php;
}

if(Request::is('admin/*))
{
    require __DIR__.'/admin_routes.php;
}
```

You can read more [here](http://easylaravel.com/split-up-routes-in-multiple-files).

Comment: Defining routes based on condition is not a good idea I think. You will not be able to generate public frontend resource urls (like post urls) from dashboard and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4):

in case someone still after that

https://ctf0.wordpress.com/2016/10/01/split-routes-into-categories-in-laravel/

1- open routes/web/api.php and add

```
foreach (File::allFiles(__DIR__ . '/Routes') as $route_file) {
  require $route_file->getPathname();
}
```

2- now create a new folder at the same level and call it ‘Routes‘

3- create files according to each route ex.user, post, stuff, etc… and add ur route logic as normal

Answer (score 3):

Laravel ^6

Explained in comments

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your Custom controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $custom_namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers\Custom';

    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

    // map new custom routes
        $this->mapCustomRoutes();
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }

   /**
     * Define the "custom" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapCustomRoutes()
    {
           Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->custom_namespace)  //or change its custom_namespace to namespace if you don't need change directory of your controllers  
            ->group(base_path('routes/custom.php')); // change custom.php to your custom routers file name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to create a custom route file you can easily add your custom route file and register by using the web middleware name. The code is pretty simple like this.

Edit App\Provider\RouteServiceProvider.php

```
   public function map()
   {
    /** Insert this Method Name **/
        $this->methodicalness();
   }

   protected function methodicalness()
   {
       Route::middleware('web')
       ->namespace($this->namespace)
       ->group(base_path('routes/yourRouteName.php'));
   }
```

Note: This method also works even the file is inside the folder just trace where your route file located.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

My simple and fast solution for multiple route files. It works!

In web.php file, add:

```
foreach (glob(__DIR__. '/*') as $router_files){
    (basename($router_files =='web.php')) ? : (require_once $router_files);
}
```