# Laravel multiple routes file for api

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes, laravel-5.4

I am working on a API for 2 client application, mobile application and angular2 admin panel.

If I write the routes for both application in a single default `routes/api.php`, this will be very huge.

So, I want to split the api routes file as :

1. `routes/admin.api.php` for angular app
2. `routes/app.api.php` for mobile app

I have modified the `RouteServiceProvide` as below

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapAdminApiRoutes();

        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api/v1')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }

    protected function mapAdminApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api/v1')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/admin.api.php'));
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Illuminate\Routing\Router::loadRoutes(): Failed opening required 'D:\Workspace\Project Izzmart\izzmart\routes/api.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
in Router.php (line 329)
```

Comment: I am not sure but I have found reference to the `api.php` routes in `RouteServiceProvider`, try adding it there underneath the existing require

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple route file istead of one main route file in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182806/multiple-route-file-istead-of-one-main-route-file-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Check your path where the route files are stored!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. create two route files: `admin.api.php` and `app.api.php`.
2. edit the `RouteServiceProvider.php` file as below:

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


    class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
        protected $apiNamespace = 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1';

        public function boot()
        {

            parent::boot();
        }

        public function map(Router $router) {
            $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
                require app_path('Http/routes/web.php');
            });
            $router->group(['namespace' => $this->apiNamespace], function ($router) {
                require app_path('Http/api.php');
            });
            $router->group(['namespace' => $this->apiNamespace], function ($router) {
                require app_path('Http/admin.api.php');
            });
        }

    }
```

For more detail see [here](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/laravel-5-multiple-routes-files).

Comment: thank you for your time really appreciate it, i have updated my post, could you please tell me what i'm missing