# Laravel - Making Routes in file other than web.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Making routes of various pages of a website in web.php makes it bulky and unstructured. So my question is is there any way to save it in separate files?

```php
// Calling Registration function
Route::any('/admin-store','AdminUserController@store')->name('admin-reg'); 

// Redirecting to Registration page
Route::get('/admin-registration','AdminUserController@index')->name('admin-registration'); 

// Redirecting to login page
Route::get('/admin-login','AdminLoginController@index')->name('admin-login'); 

// Redirecting to Admin Profile Page
Route::get('/admin-profile','AdminProfileController@index')->name('admin-profile'); 

// Calling Login function
Route::post('admin-login-result','AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin-log'); 

// Calling Function to Update Profile
Route::post('admin-edit-profile','AdminEditController@updateProfile')
         ->name('admin-edit-profile'); 

// Redirecting to Profile Edit page
Route::get('/admin-edit-profile','AdminEditController@index')->name('admin-edit');
```

Comment: yes you can, save the routes in different files according to your requirement and include those files in web.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple route file istead of one main route file in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182806/multiple-route-file-istead-of-one-main-route-file-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes, you can store routes in different files.

---

## Expanded answer

### 1 - Create your new Route file

Create your new route file, for this example I'll name it `users.php` and store there the related routes:

- **routes/users.php**

```php
  Route::get('/my-fancy-route', 'MyCoolController@anAwesomeFunction');
  // and the rest of your code.
```

### 2 - Add your route file to the RouteServiceProvider

Add here a new method, i'll call it `mapUserRoutes`:

- **app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php**

```php
/**
 * Define the User routes of the application.
 *
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapUserRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('v1')  // if you need to specify a route prefix
        ->middleware('auth:api') // specify here your middlewares
        ->namespace($this->namespace) // leave it as is
        /** the name of your route goes here: */
        ->group(base_path('routes/users.php'));
}
```

### 3 - Add it to the `map()` method

In the same file(`RouteServiceProvider.php`), go to the top and add your new method inside the `map()` function:

```php
/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function map()
{

    // some other mapping actions

    $this->mapUserRoutes();
}
```

### 4 - Final steps

I'm not fully sure if this is neccesary but never hurts to do:

- Stop your server (if runing)
- do `php artisan config:clear`
- Start your server.

Comment: Got error: Class excel(name of my new route file) does not exist

Comment: Did you update the `->group(base_path('path/to/route/file.php'));`?