# laravel routes folder structuring

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm new to laravel but I know that laravel folder structure can be customised.

So this is the default routes folder structure and files in laravel

[default laravel routes structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHGjX.png)

I want to ***separate my routes into smaller groups of folder, and each path contain file with same name*** to have clear image of each routes belong to which module, something like this

[what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oNhU.png)

Hence I can separate the routes clearly as there are multiple developers working on the project

**Is that possible to do so?**

**What file do I need to configure after I have this kind of structure to make it work?**

I get some idea from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/5rq8ki/how_you_structure_your_routes/). But this is in ***app*** folder, I want to do it in ***routes*** folder

Thank you in advance for any solution.

Comment: One way to do it, is to load all routes in your subdirectory from one of the default route files (.e.g routes/web.php). Have a look at this question for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182806/multiple-route-file-instead-of-one-main-route-file-in-laravel-5

Comment: thx for the reply, I found what I want, I share it here in case anyone looking for the same things https://medium.com/@thesourav/organize-your-laravel-routes-for-better-and-maintainable-code-4ad9b76aed0f